# What extra data is stored by an anonymous function?

Tags: matlab

I have learned recently that anonymous functions can carry around large amounts of unused data, even if this data is created after the anonymous function is instantiated. The following example, together with the FUNCTIONS comand, illustrates this,

```
function fun=test %place in an mfile

        a=1;
        b=2;
        c=3;

        fun=@(x)x+b+a;

        a=7;
        b=rand(1000);
        c=5;

        q=3;
        r=4;
end
```

Now, back in the base workspace, when I apply the functions() command to 'fun', I see

```
>> fun=test; s=functions(fun); s.workspace{:}

    ans = 
          b: 2
          a: 1

    ans = 
          fun: @(x)x+b+a
            a: 1
            b: [1000x1000 double]
            c: 3
```

I would like to understand (with official documentation if possible) what rules anonymous functions use to decide what data to carry around. The above seems to suggest that `s.workspace{1}` will always contain the external variables and their values that the anonymous function actually uses. Meanwhile `s.workspace{2}` seems to contain updates to variables that came into scope *before* `fun` was defined. Am I correct that these are the rules? But if so, then why, in the above, does `s.workspace{2}` contain an update to b, but not to a and c?

These things seem important to understand, since obviously, I can end up carrying large amounts of unintended memory that was allocated after my anonymous function was created.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of the anonymous function is totally correct. The question is, why `a` and `c` are not updated and `q` and `r` not shown. Matlab does some code analyse and removes every irrelevant line. Neither the variable is read nor a function is called. Compare the behavior with this code:

```
function fun=test %place in an mfile

        a=1;
        b=2;
        c=3;

        fun=@(x)x+b+a;

        a=7;
        b=rand(1000);
        c=5;

        q=3;
        r=4;
        eval('');

end
```

Because of the `eval('')` the code analyse can't identify any irrelevant lines. The output is:

```
ans = 

    b: 2
    a: 1


ans = 

    fun: @(x)x+b+a
      a: 7
      b: [1000x1000 double]
      c: 5
      q: 3
      r: 4
```

Comment: Thanks, though,  I still don't quite understand the "relevance" rules. Nothing that happens after `fun` is defined should be relevant, should it? An anonymous function is supposed to reference the workspace as it exists at the time the anonymous function is created.

Comment: Code optimization does not remove all irrelevant lines, but every removed line is irrelevant. It would be best to remove all irrelevant line, but it's to complicated. The `b=rand(1000)` is not removed because it changes the state of the random number generator. A "perfect" code optimization would reduce everything after `fun...` to `rand(1000)`

Comment: I see. Well, just have to be careful with anonymous functions, I guess. Incidentally, I don't think `b=rand(1000)` is retained because of the random number generator. After creating `fun`, assigning any non-scalar to a, b, or c seems to cause those updates to be retained.

Comment: Assigning any non scalar does not make the line relevant, but the code optimization does not remove the line. Two different things. Maybe you should stop thinking about artificial examples and use some real code ;)

Comment: **Maybe you should stop thinking about artificial examples and use some real code ;)** Not sure what that would serve. Regardless of the reason `b=rand(1000)` is retained, the outcome is equally bad!

Comment: **A "perfect" code optimization would reduce everything after fun... to rand(1000)** I didn't quite understand that, now that I think of it. Surely the "perfect" code optimization would completely ignore everything that happens after `fun` is created. Even if it can't find all irrelevant lines, surely those are easy to disqualify, no?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is at best a partial answer. What has been demonstrated is that the "baggage" the anonymous function carries with it depends on the analyzability of the code, which is broken by `eval`. What is not addressed is the question why `b` is updated, but `a` isn't.

Comment: To me this looks like there's a bug, because optimization should never affect functionality. But here the return value of the anonymous function depends on the update of `a`, and that in turn on the presence of `eval('')`.

Comment: @A.Donda The output of fun(x) for any given x remains unchanged, regardless of the presence of `eval('')`, so not sure what you mean by "affecting functionality".

Comment: @MattJ, I admit I haven't tested this, but according to the data in your question and this answer, depending on whether the `eval´ is there or not, the value of `a` associated with `fun` changes from 1 to 7. The output of `fun` must therefore change, too. If not, the whole thing makes even less sense.

Comment: @A.Donda No it does not change, because the relevant variable is the first one `b: 2 a: 1`.

Comment: Ok, reading is apparently advantageous... ;-) So, after doing that it appears to me that a) I was wrong about there being a bug b) @MattJ is probably right about `s.workspace{1}`, and that is the only part of `workspace` that is mentioned in the documentation, and c) `s.workspace{2}` is completely undocumented. Do you two agree?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671549/matlab-function-handle-workspace-shenanigans

Comment: The caller workspace is not explicit documented, but required. To avoid memory issues, the only practical solution seems to add some cleanup before returning: `vars_to_delete=setdiff(who,'fun');vars_to_delete{end+1}='vars_to_delete';clear(vars_to_delete{:});`